# add text inside a rect in force layout graph d3.js REACTJS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs

I am trying to display text in the middle of a rect using ReactJS. I have tried it in allow of different ways but the text always ends up ouside the graph on the right side.

I am trying to do the following:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7341714

I am getting the following result:

[image]

How can I get the number 60 to appear in the middle of the rect?

Here is my code:

```
   var BarChart = React.createClass({

      getInitialState: function () {
        return {props: this.props};
      },

      componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
          props: nextProps
        });
      },

      render: function() {
        return (
          <svg width={this.state.props.width} height={this.state.props.height}>
            <g  style={{strokeWidth:4, stroke:"black"}}>
              <rect fill={"white"} width={146} height={18}/>  
              <text> {this.state.props.propValue} </text>
            </g>
          </svg>
        );
      }
```

Comment: I can only add the text inside the bar if I replace {this.state.props.propValue}  with a non React JS variable.
If I replace it with simple letters the text will appear inside properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution but I don't know exactly why this issue is occurring. The value inside `<text> </text>` must be a string value and `{this.state.props.propValue}` is an integer.

I added .toString() to `{this.state.props.propValue}` and my issue was resolved.

Here is the end result:

[image]

Solved Code:

```
     render: function() {
        var val = this.state.props.propValue;
        return (
          <svg width={this.state.props.width} height={this.state.props.height}>
            <g style={{strokeWidth:2, stroke:"black"}}>
             <rect fill={"white"} width={146} height={18}  y={1} x={1}/>
            </g>
            <DataSeries data={this.state.props.propValue} width={w} height={h} color={this.state.props.propColor} /> 
            <text> {val.toString()} </text>
          </svg>
        );
```